# How to close account?

Tags: account

I am trying to close an account with a balance of 890880 lamport (getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption api result) for rent, and I send a transaction to transfer the 885880 amount via system transfer. However, I get an error message "insufficient funds for rent".

How can I reduce the balance to zero? The account owner is system program.　Is a balance of 890880 not enough?

Answer (score 4):

for closing the account account, you need to "reduce" the lamports at account to 0. While lamports at account can be of whatever amount it cannot be in range of >0,<rentExempt. The minimal amount of lamports of rent exempt in the account is defined differently for account type, depending on the space needed for allocation.

Un your case I wonder you refer to create account with `890880` while trying to transfer out only `885880`. The rest of the difference on the numbers is about to be left in the account and is fewer to minimal required rent exempt value.

Answer (score 2):

Which wallets paying the fee? If the same
wallet is paying the fee subtract 5000 lamports, and if youre paying the fee from a separate wallet dont subtract the 5000.